# Adding units to pgfplots nodes in column chart

Tags: pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

The picture below is almost what I need and is generated by the MWE below. All I require is to include percentage symbols on the labels on the nodes. So they should read: 34%, 22% and 13%.

[image]

----------- MWE ---------------------

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    nodes near coords,
    xtick=data
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A,34)
        (B,22)
        (C,13)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Finally, a well-crafted MWE :).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default `nodes near coords` prints `\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}`. You can add a percent sign by saying

```
nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%
```

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    nodes near coords=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}\%,
    xtick=data
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A,34)
        (B,22)
        (C,13)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very useful! This will go into my collection.

Answer (score 4):

- Based on [Text nodes for nodes near coords](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350129) I added a custom/explicit `point meta`.
- Of course, **[Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%C3%B8rn-t)** answer is better since you don't have to repeat the values.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350129
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={A,B,C},
    nodes near coords,
    point meta=explicit symbolic,
    xtick=data,
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=blue] coordinates {
        (A,34) [34 \%]
        (B,22) [22 \%]
        (C,13) [13 \%]
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]